# google hangout chat can bots message bots?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I have a use scenario where I'm testing a bot in google hangout. To facilitate testing of multiple users, I'd like to create a series of other bots that replicate the functions of users. But this is all dependent on the bots in the room listening to one another. It also requires that I get the userid of the bots so they can name each other. In Google Scripts I can find no way to retrieve that (the rest API is not an option).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is documented, but I understand GCP docs aren't the easiest to navigate. According to the [Event Format reference](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events#message): "Only messages from "real", non-bot users are delivered to bots. A bot will never receive messages posted by itself or by a different bot."

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to the question appears to be no. Bots do not appear to be able to talk to each other. When you put the userid in the text property of the bot it does not replace it to an @botname as it does with human users. If anyone can figure out another way to do it I would appreciate it.

But the second question of where to get the bots userid I can now answer and I leave here in case anyone else is curious. This appears only in a message event, when a bot is mentioned as the property `event.message.annotations[0].userMention.user.name`